# How to calculate number rows in SQL query limited result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch only 20 rows from a database table using one condition 
for example :

```
select * from orders where price > 10000 limit 0,20
```

Above query will fetch only 20 rows. Is there any way i can get how many rows it can fetch with same condition in WHERE clause when `limit 0,20` is not used?. I have to do it in one single query.

Please guide me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT
>   clause to restrict the number of rows
>   the server returns to the client. In
>   some cases, it is desirable to know
>   how many rows the statement would have
>   returned without the LIMIT, but
>   without running the statement again.
>   To obtain this row count, include a
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the
>   SELECT statement, and then invoke
>   FOUND_ROWS() afterward.

Comment: My pleasure Forte, enjoy your coding!

Answer (score 0):

This?
`select count(*) from orders where price > 10000`

Comment: i wanted rows count, all field's values and limited number of rows. But above query will only give rows count.